# Function not starting when scroll point is over top of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I use a scrollTop function to start animations, delays, etc when the div is scrolled to. It works for other things on my page, but for some reason, this function is not working and it loads on page load.

Does anyone see anything wrong in my code? This can be seen live here:

```
<div class="blue-box-container">
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
    var oTop = $('.blue-box-container').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        console.log(pTop + ' - ' + oTop);
        if (pTop > oTop) {
            blueBoxDelays();
        }
    });
});
$('.fadeBlock').css('display', 'none');
blueBoxDelays();

function blueBoxDelays() {
    var delay = 0;
    $('.fadeBlock').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(400 + delay).fadeIn(1000);
        delay = 200 * (i + 1);
    });
};
```

Comment: is this wrapped in a <script> tag?

Comment: Yes it is in the script tag.

Comment: What do you see in the debugger when you debug it?

Comment: There aren't any errors.

Comment: blueBoxDelays() is being called no matter the result of the scroll calculation. have you tried removing the call right below $('.fadeBlock')...?

Comment: Yes. That doesn't allow the boxes to delay and fadeIn. It doesn't show anything if I do that.

Comment: It'll be better if you can make a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Could you remove that script tag from the HTML and create a separate javascript file and then include it? Just to be able to debug it. Or may be a jsfiddle demo

Comment: I'm trying to create its own js file, but the js file won't even load,

Comment: Nevermind, I got it into its own file.

Comment: I extracted your code to a fiddle and it works correctly https://jsfiddle.net/26jw7Low/2/ (Copy pasted from your snippet). You might try adjusting the condition which triggers the animation or increasing the delay and see if that helps.

Comment: @Raevenk How does that work? If you wait to scroll down at all, you will see that all of the animations are complete. Every where else I have this code, the animation starts once you scroll over-top of the div. The piece of code `blueBoxDelays();` under `$('.fadeBlock').css('display', 'none');` is what I believe is causing it, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Paul correct. You just need to remove the call to blueBoxDelays() which is outside of the initial function. Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/26jw7Low/3/ If that doesn't work then there is most likely a conflict with another script.

Comment: @Raevenk That did it! The thing is, I tried doing that before I posted this question. Do you think because I moved the JS to its own separate file, that allowed me to do it?

Comment: @Paul it's possible that moving the script indeed solved the issue, not sure how you had it set up initially but perhaps the script was firing too soon. Happy to hear that it's working.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will approve your answer if you create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted your code to a fiddle and it works correctly https://jsfiddle.net/26jw7Low/3/, you just need to remove the call to blueBoxDelays() which is outside of the initial function as seen below.

```
$(function() {
    var oTop = $('.blue-box-container').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        console.log(pTop + ' - ' + oTop);
        if (pTop > oTop) {
            blueBoxDelays();
        }
    });
});
$('.fadeBlock').css('display', 'none');
// REMOVE THIS blueBoxDelays();

function blueBoxDelays() {
    var delay = 0;
    $('.fadeBlock').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(400 + delay).fadeIn(1000);
        delay = 200 * (i + 1);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `$('.fadeBlock').css('display', 'none');` maybe not yet execute

You can put it to `$(function(){})` end try again:

```
$(function() {
    $('.fadeBlock').css('display', 'none');
    var oTop = $('.blue-box-container').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        console.log(pTop + ' - ' + oTop);
        if (pTop > oTop) {
            blueBoxDelays();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It still runs before I get over top of it with the scroll.

Comment: Do you actually WANT to remove and  fadein the blocks again on scroll though? If that's the case just add that display to none part right above the blueBoxDelays() in the if statement.